# Check Streaming URL for Valid

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I check to see if a URL is valid (one that streams)? I've tried opening the stream (not reading data) but it still gets caught up on the stream and it tries downloading the entire stream which doesn't stop.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question further please. Such as code on what you are trying to do and the exact technologies you are using.

Comment: Technology is Windows Phone 7 (Silverlight) and I need to check to see if a URL is valid (not just a valid URI but actually has returns a response. Right now when I feed a url that doesn't exist to `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track` it doesn't return any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what you are trying to do isn't specifically Windows Phone 7 but trying to see if there is a file on the other end.

This link here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/e2bb41aa-a2ee-4751-8028-b9c5e291f255 details a way to do it. Look at the accepted answer.

Comment: That's actually really useful and close to what I found before. The problem with Windows Phone is that everything is async so I need a way to use this with `BeginGetResponse` and `EndGetResponse` which is where I am getting trouble as those seem to try to download the entire file.

Comment: This is not the answer for the question but this answer might help on another platform that doesn't require async calls.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help Gabriel, I was unable to find any asynchronous examples quick enough. Though I am certain you could modify the above code to act asynchronously.